# "I was more talking along the lines of..."?

Tags: word-usage

Can 'more' be used before a present participle?

I'm wondering if this usage is grammatically correct, because I remember it being used in such a way but can't find any instances using google. Here's an example of what I'm talking about:

> I was more using it in the sense of *blah blah blah*.

or

> I was more talking along the lines of...

If it is incorrect, is there another alternative that can get the same meaning across?

Comment: Go to Google, type "define more".  Is it an adverb?  If so it can be used as a verb modifier.

Comment: I know that it can be used to modify certain verbs by using it after the verb, but I was more wondering if it's allowable when used before a verb.

Comment: Sure.  "My dog was more inhaling his food than eating it."

Comment: It's part of the comparative construction and it can modify any constituent type. Normally it modifies predicates (verb phrases and especially predicate adjectives). When you see a comparative word like _more_, look around for the rest of the construction. There's always a _than_ clause, giving the baseline comparison, which is often deleted in context. The first S means something like "I was more using it in the sense of blah blah blah (than I was intending for you to take it literally)", and it's perfectly grammatical.

Comment: Ok, thank you. The reason I was wary was because the way I used it doesn't seem like the dictionary definition of 'more'. Instead I was using it as an equivalent of 'as opposed to'. Thanks Greg and John.

Comment: "I was using it **more** in the sense of blah blah blah;" "I was talking **more** along the lines of..." HTH

Comment: @HotLicks Have you gone there? What have you found?

Comment: @Kris - Yes, and one sense is listed as an adverb.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is grammatical usage in informal English. People say this all the time, using 'more' in this position as a sentence adverb. It is very informal: it sounds somewhat infelicitous in a formal setting, and you would not use it in print.

The meaning is synonymous with 'rather', it is providing an alternative to a prior mentioned situation.

> Didn't the fire alarm scare you?
>
> No, I was more sauntering towards the exit than running.

A present participle isn't necessary following it.

> How was the play?
>
> It was more a skit than a play.

or

> Did you have fun on your vacation in Brazil?
>
> It was more that I was on a business trip. I didn't get to see much.

Answer (score 0):

In a comment, John Lawler wrote:

> It's part of the comparative construction and it can modify any constituent type. Normally it modifies predicates (verb phrases and especially predicate adjectives). When you see a comparative word like *more*, look around for the rest of the construction. There's always a *than* clause, giving the baseline comparison, which is often deleted in context. The first S means something like "I was more using it in the sense of blah blah blah (than I was intending for you to take it literally)", and it's perfectly grammatical.